# How can I use the labels from cv2.kmeans as index for a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, numpy

I am looking at the code from [here](https://github.com/kavishdahekar/IITG-Captcha-Solver-OpenCV-TensorFlow/blob/master/data_preparation/segregate.py). And I can't get it to run nor get in touch with the developer. I have made some modifications to get it to work but I cant figure out why I am getting the error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

I've printed the type and I've noticed that its type is `<class 'list'>`. I've tried to lookup various resources but just can't understand what is causing the issue.

```
# applying kmeans on colwise white pixel counts
z = np.float32(a)
# Define criteria = ( type, max_iter = 10 , epsilon = 1.0 )
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 12, 0.0)
# Set flags (Just to avoid line break in the code)
flags = cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS
K = 5
# Apply KMeans
compactness,labels,centers = cv2.kmeans(z,K,None,criteria,10,flags)

# define colors to be used
blue = np.array([255,0,0])
green = np.array([0,255,0])
red = np.array([0,0,255])
tur = np.array([255,255,0])
purple = np.array([255,0,255])
yellow = np.array([0,255,255])

colors = [red,green,blue,purple,tur]
imcpy = np.empty_like(img)
np.copyto(imcpy,img)

# draw colors according to cluster labels
for i in range(len(a)):
        row,col = a[i][0],a[i][1]
        thisColor = colors[labels[i]]
        imcpy[row][col] = thisColor

for c in range(len(centers)):
        Crow,Ccol = centers[c][0],int(centers[c][1])
        for row in range(height):
                imcpy[row][Ccol] = np.array([255,255,255])

# characters
charHeight, charWidth = height,45
char_imgs = []
centers = sorted(centers,key=lambda x: x[1])
for c in range(len(centers)):
        Crow,Ccol = centers[c][0],int(centers[c][1])
        x1 = (Ccol-int(charWidth/2)) if ((Ccol-int(charWidth/2)) > 0) else 0
        x2 = (Ccol+int(charWidth/2)) if ((Ccol+int(charWidth/2)) < width) else width
        char_imgs.append(charcpy[0:height , x1:x2])

for x in range(len(char_imgs)):
        opPath = outDIR+"/"+ chars[x]
        if not os.path.exists(opPath):
                os.makedirs(opPath)
        cv2.imwrite(opPath +"/" + str(x) +"_" + file, char_imgs[x])
```

Error:

```
/prep# python3 prepdata.py ../images/train_120.png 
Traceback (most recent call last): File "prepdata.py", line 95, in <module> thisColor = colors[labels[i]] 
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: could you print the whole error message please.

Answer (score 0):

This exception happens if you try to index a Python list (your `colors`) with an NumPy array (even if it's just integers):

```
import numpy as np

color = ['red', 'blue', 'yellow']
labels = np.array([[1, 2], [2, 3]])
color[labels[1]]
```

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Just looking at an example of [`cv2.kmeans`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.3.0/samples/python/kmeans.py#L41) makes it clear that you should flatten (`ravel`) your `labels`, i.e.:

```
labels = labels.ravel()
```